# How to add headers to a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, csv

I have a csv file like this:

```
Martin  2/12/17 ECPM_medio  0.23    smaller than    0.27    Incremento
Martin  2/12/17 Fill_rate   1.53%   smaller than    2.19%   Incremento
```

I want to add some headers and save my CSV:

```
Cliente Fecha   Data        Numbers Info            Numbers2 Analisys
Martin  2/12/17 ECPM_medio  0.23    smaller than    0.27    Incremento
Martin  2/12/17 Fill_rate   1.53%   smaller than    2.19%   Incremento
```

I work with python 2.7. I can use CSV or Pandas libs!

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas, read file without headers.
Add Columns names as a list.
Save file to the csv.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=None, index_col=None)
df.columns = ['Cliente', 'Fecha', 'Data', 'Numbers', 'Info', 'Numbers2', 'Analisys']
df.to_csv("file.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method to_csv() must be called with DataFrame instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`

Comment: @MartinBouhier See edits to this answer.

Comment: @JtMiclat The functions you used in this answer are all deprecated/removed. Either accept the edit or have your answer downvoted.